# How to host multiple websites on a single domain on IIS without affecting others performance?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Let me tell you the scenario. I have a single IIS server for e.g www.xyz.com, and i have to host multiple websites like www.xyz.com/A, www.xyz.com/B, www.xyz.com/C.
I can host them with in different three application pool. But some time due to slow down of one website my other websites also slows down.

so my question is if there is any way of hosting these websites in case of issue with one , it would not affect other website performace.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're doing seems like have a different **directory** on a domain for each of your websites. So all you need to do is deploy each site to a different directory on your IIS site. My wording is rough and not clear so that's why I haven't posted an answer

Comment: No this will not solve my problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Find out why slowness happens (many ways to profile performance and analyze performance if you use a search engine, but the original developers should work on that), and that would tell what's up and how to fix. Don't ever guess and such questions won't be welcome.